# Is there a math function that increases when >0 and constant when <0 WITHOUT using piecewise functions

Tags: math, calculus, differential-equations

Is there a mathematical function that is constant at 0, but once it hits 0, it begins increasing. I dont care what kind of increasing function it is: e, parabola, etc. 
I am trying to avoid piecewise function.

Comment: Do you mean it is constant up to but not including 0, and increasing after that?

Comment: Try [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You mean like `x + abs(x)`?  If not, your question is massively underspecified.

Comment: @Josh, Yes, exactly. Constant up to 0, and increasing after that. I don't care if 0 is included or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is `x + abs(x)`, though technically `abs(x)` is itself piecewise.

If you want something smoother, then try `x^3 + abs(x^3)`, or any higher, odd exponent.

And another option that avoids using `abs` and is actually continuous: `x + sqrt(x^2)`

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but in a sense `abs()` is a piecewise function.  It's certainly not differentiable and it's implemented with a conditional internally.

Comment: @Chris: You're right, and I wrote so much in my answer. Here's another option that is not piecewise.

Comment: @Chris A. abs() is often a native instruction, so it avoids the overhead of conditionals in the resulting code.